# Vim go to line/column with --remote-silent

Tags: vim

I'm trying to open a file using mvim (that comes with MacVim) and open it at a certain line/column using remote-silent mode (the mode that reuses the same open window). I cannot get that to work. I'm using version 7.4 (71), the latest version in MacPorts.

I've tried the following:

I want to go to line 100 and column 5. So I issue the following command:

```
mvim +"normal gg 99j 0 4l" code.cpp
```

which works great. Now I want to do it in remote-silent mode. Like this:

```
mvim --remote-silent  +"normal gg 99j 0 4l" code.cpp
```

It goes to line 100 but it ignores the rest. I've tried a couple of other commands for example gg99j$ and it also ignores the $.

What am I doing wrong? How can I go to a line/column in mvim, invoked from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your commands a little bit.

Open `filename` in MacVim and jump to line 100, column 5:

```
$ mvim +"100G5|" filename
```

"Silently" open `filename` in MacVim and jump to line 100, column 5:

```
$ mvim --remote-silent +"100G5|" filename
```

Jump to line 200, column 12 in MacVim's current buffer:

```
$ mvim --remote-send "200G12|"
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried and it says: Not an editor command: 100G5||cal foreground()|if &im|star|en|redr|f

Comment: Sounds like pipe escaping issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could also call a function to do the movement for you.

```
mvim "+call cursor(100,5)" filename
```